# Embedded XML views; Using the parent view's controller

Tags: sapui5

I am developing an app where I have create, display and change views.

I want to share the screen between these views, but I thought embedding the whole screen as a fragment is not advisable because fragments are for small reusable pieces.

However, embedding the screen as a view means I have to specify a controller, but I want to use the parent view's controller, as that implements the logic of the create/display/change action. (The views have some shared functions in a library file).

Is there a way that I can embed a view but still use the parent view's controller, or should I embed the screen as a fragment?

Comment: Have a look if this will answer your question: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/df8c9c3d79b54c928855162bafcd88ee

Comment: @DubZ I read that page before posting the question and it does not. Can you be more specific?

Comment: then I might you ask that you could describe a bit more in detail what you want to achieve. In the link I have posted is described, how you can embed an XML view into another XML view. And in the XML view you can define which controller should be loaded. Of course you can define the same controller like in your parent view.

Comment: That's right, but if the same view is embedded in several other views, how do I define the controller of the parent view? That is what I am asking. It does not seem possible with XML views. I assume in Javascript you could load the view and assign a controller dynamically, but I am wanting to use XML views.